# Bootstrap collapse menu doesn't work

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I've just installed bootstrap 3 but the collapsing menu doesn't work;
The menu looks fine in a desktop screen but scaling the hole thing down the menu button doesn't show up..

Here is the code for the menu:

```
<div id="menu">
<div class="navbar navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
  <div class="container">
  <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#nav-collapse">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </a>

    <a class="navbar-brand" href="/"><img class="top-logo" src="img/hotels.nl_.jpg" alt="Hotels.nl"></a>
    <div id=".nav-collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">

    <li class="active"><a href="#">Inloggen <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Taal <span class="caret"></span></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Nederlands</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">English</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">German</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Valuta<span class="caret"></span></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Euro</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Dollar</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Pond</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div><!--End container-->
</div><!--End fixedtop-->
```

Comment: Have you included the correct JS file?

Comment: i'v tried several but now i have 2.1.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you've put the jquery library , and after you've put the js file of bootstrap , I can think that the problem is with the data-target.

You're targeting the element with the id "nav-collapse", and you have ".nav-collapse" as id, so you need to take off that dot.

```
<div id="menu">
<div class="navbar navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
  <div class="container">
  <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#nav-collapse">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </a>

    <a class="navbar-brand" href="/"><img class="top-logo" src="img/hotels.nl_.jpg" alt="Hotels.nl"></a>
    <div id="nav-collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">

    <li class="active"><a href="#">Inloggen <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Taal <span class="caret"></span></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Nederlands</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">English</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">German</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Valuta<span class="caret"></span></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Euro</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Dollar</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Pond</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div><!--End container-->
</div><!--End fixedtop-->
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s0sv1ev6/), and I changed some classes and some stuff to make the menu visible. Because if you didn't have the right CSS for it, it's pretty messed up like this.

And Note that you should always refer to the bootstrap docs , and try to stick to their methods to make your menu or anything else works perfectly fine.

And I saw that you've put the class "pull-right" for the menu , there's a class called "navbar-right" that works better that just pulling the menu to the right I think.

Comment: Thanks for responding! i'v put the jquery indeed i also removed de dot like you said but still nothing happen..

Comment: @sanderbloem : See the fiddle that I mentioned in the edited response.. and if you can, provide a fiddle containing all your code (html, css) for the meny you're using and i'll fix it.

Comment: Nice 1 step closer.. tried your fiddle and for the screens of 480 and smaller it works! Thanks!

Comment: Great, you should always refer to the documentation in getbootstrap.com , this is better..

Comment: your so right! maybe im doing something wrong but working in dreamweaver with fluid grids maybe the combination of those two breaks everything..

Comment: do you have a suggestion to make it work on the viewport 481 till 769?

Comment: The fiddle is working until 786px , I think you're missing something, and for the button toggling the menu, in your example it's an anchor tag ('<a>'), I think it's better to be a button , and also, I think you should give the div that'll collapse the classes : collapse and navbar-collapse..

Comment: And as a new member in this community , I suggest that you take a tour in it : [Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) , so you can know how to deal with questions and answers